# how do I make a picture box go down in vb

Tags: vb.net

I've updated the code and now it says that index was outside of the bounds of the array and also I'm in cs1 in high school, and accidentally made this account using my school google account.
I have included the code specific to moving the bricks down (by just a little), the code for the array, and the code for the entire timer block which as you can see is very organized with regions

```
Dim newbrickx, newbricky As Integer
newbrickx = bricks(i).Location.X
newbricky = bricks(i).Location.Y + 10
        'left wall
        If (lblball.Location.X >= Me.ClientSize.Width - lblball.Width) Then
            bricks(i).Location = New Point(newbrickx, newbricky)
        End If
        'right wall
        If (lblball.Location.X = 0) Then
            bricks(i).Location = New Point(newbrickx, newbricky)
        End If
```

the array (in the form load event)

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bricks = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4, PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8}
  End Sub
```

Comment: Your `if` statements are only looking at the `X` area.

Comment: Do you want `bricks(i)` instead of just `bricks` inside the conditional block?

Comment: Is `lblball` a Label or the PictureBox in question?  What is moving the  `lblball`?

Comment: the `lblball` is being moved by code further up in the code. I tried doing `bricks(i)` and it didn't work also in form load all the "bricks" are being defined in an array. and the `if` statements do not need to look at the `Y` area as they are only looking at when the ball hits the wall the need to move down a little, also sorry for the poor editing I'm new to StackOverflow

Comment: We clearly need to see more code.  Your code is checking the location of `lblball` but we don't see what's moving that.  We don't see how `bricks` is being used.

Comment: I updated the question post

Comment: Arrays are zero based.  You didn't show your loop, but make sure `i` is one less than the count.

Comment: thanks and its actually a timer with a tick interval of "10" so how would I do this

Comment: By not showing us enough relevant code, you do make this hard to help you.  How do we know what's in your tick event?  Don't increment your variable if it's equal or exceeds the count.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry if this is a wrong question to ask here but, could I get your email so I can email you the code in the timer

Comment: No, edit your post with the relevant code.

Comment: ok but when I added the entire timer code it said that it was mostly code. which which part of the timer do you think you need

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to write comments yet, so I do it this way.
I assume bricks is an array containing your pictureboxes. So, inside the conditional block you can assign the new position like this:

```
  bricks(i).Location = New Point(newbrickx, newbricky)
```

And as commented before you should probably also check for the y coordinates to make sure it is not out of bounds.

Comment: You will need to refresh form to repaint changes or use DoEvents() method.

Comment: @SepehrDavarnia `DoEvents` is never the answer.

Comment: @LarsTech yes, Accutally using DoEvents means bad code! but it still works.

Comment: I updated the question post

Comment: We will need more of your code to see how you are using the bricks array. Also you are checking the position of lblball and then move a brick, which does not seem to make sense. And lastly it looks like you mixed up left and right wall. lblball.Location.X = 0 is the left bound of the area.